# How to import mongodb's ObjectId when it is not possible to install mongodb?

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I am developing a react based Wordpress plugin. I can install any package from npmjs, but not mongodb. If to so, it will raise different errors.

But backend uses mongodb, and so types has mongodb types like ObjectId. I tries using `bson-objectid` but its `ObjectId` is not accepted by mongodb.

i.e. I can not insert record. What can I do?

error:

```
Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OptionalId<Document>'.
  Type 'User' is not assignable to type '{ _id?: ObjectId; }'.
    Types of property '_id' are incompatible.
      Type 'ObjectID' is missing the following properties from type 'ObjectId': _bsontype, toJSON, inspect
```

here:

```
await db.collection('users').insertOne(user)
```

when:

```
import ObjectId from 'bson-objectid'

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<AuthResponse>
) {
    const user: User = {
        _id: new ObjectId(),
        email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        name,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        verificationToken,
    }
```

And type is here:

```
import ObjectId from 'bson-objectid'

export interface User {
    _id: ObjectId
```

---

truth is I way a bit easy, I did not implemented DTO for easy entity, and I only use entity on client side also, if I would do all conversion, it would not happen, but if possible I would not convert all model -> dot